# Halt the computation when it encounters a Symbol?

Tags: evaluation, symbols

Is there a way to stop the evaluation of an expression when the result of that expression would depend on the value of a Symbol?

```
f[g[x_]] := 2
g[1] := 3

f[g[1]]
f[3]
f[g[x]]
2
```

Here I would like to halt the execution when it tries to apply `g[1]-> 3` to `g[x]` and fails.
Basically is there a way to make the evaluation of an expression and the replacement of its Symbols commutative?

Answer (score 3):

Possibly you need only the functionality provided by the [`HoldFirst`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldFirst.html), [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html), or [`HoldRest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldRest.html) attributes, e.g.

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]

f[g[1]]
f[3]
f[g[x]]
```

> ```
> 2
>
> f[3]
>
> 2
> ```

If this doesn't do all that you want could you give more examples of the behavior you desire?